# `unknown` type is coerced to `string`, despite official semantics for `unknown`

Tags: typescript, coercion

I've read the official doc about the unknown type but I have some difficulties to really understand how it works.

One can read in the doc : "no operations are permitted on an unknown without first asserting or narrowing to a more specific type."

but if I have this function:

```
const foo = (x: unknown) => {
  return x + "3";
}
```

it's ok for TypeScript, but this function raises an error, telling that x is unknown:

```
const foo = (x: unknown) => {
  return x + 3;
}
```

why does it work with x + "3" ?

If casting is involved, true + 3 or {} + 3 works for instance, as well as true + "3".

Comment: Odd. I assume it's no matter what you insert into foo, when you do `+ '3'` the result will always be a string and hence it's "known"? Seems buggish to me though.

Comment: @k0pernikus Interesting. That could be...

Comment: I tried basically every version of on the TypeScript playground and every version starting from 3.3.333 up until the nightly version features this strange behavior. You may open a bug report for this on [their github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Even `const foo = (x: unknown) => { const y = '3'; return x + y;}` has the same behavior. This gotta be a bug.

Comment: If you type `foo` return value, at least it would throw when doing `foo = (x: unknown): number => {...}` but it will still gladly allow `foo = (x: unknown): string => {...}`

Comment: I will continue to search if it's really a bug and eventually open a bug report. Thank you @k0pernikus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Typescript's designers have chosen to allow *unchecked* many of Javascript's implicit coercions, typically because they are so idiomatic.

[Suggestion: stricter operators #7989](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7989):

> Currently operators like "+" are defined such that they match their semantics in JS. The below are all allowed by the compiler and produce the shown values, even with `--strictNullChecks` on.
>
> - `2 + 'a'` => `"2a"`
> - `null + 'a'` => `"nulla"` (!)
> - `2 - null` => `2`

The Typescript maintainers have kept this issue open, suggesting that they are open to changing this, or at least adding a new compiler strictness flag.

Project lead Ryan Cavanaugh says:

> Approved behavior change: under `--strictNullChecks` it should be an error to use a possibly-null/possibly-undefined operand in a `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `|`, `&`, `^`, or `**` expression. One exception is that `string + nullable` is still OK since that's very common for producing debugging strings.

Answer (score 0):

In type-checking a `+` binary expression, if at least one operand is a string (in this case `"3"`), then the compiler infers the whole expression as a string.

Taken from the comments in `checkBinaryLikeExpressionWorker` (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/checker.ts#L32087)

> If *both* operands are of the Number primitive type, the result is of
> the Number primitive type.
> If *one or both* operands are of the String primitive type, the result
> is of the String primitive type.

In the case of `x + 3`, the "number" test fails and in the end, the expression is typed `any` and an error is reported .

Comment: This is telling the asker what they already know. The question is, *'why does it work with x + "3"?'*